# Prevent BlocBuilder from repeating/multiple triggers

Tags: flutter, bloc

**Bloc State**

```
sealed class PostState extends Equatable {
  const PostState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class CommentState extends PostState {
  const CommentState({
   required this.commentIndex,
  });

  final int commentIndex;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [commentIndex];
}
```

**BlocBuilder**

```
return BlocBuilder<PostBloc, PostState>(
  builder: (context, postState) {
    if (postState is CommentState) {
      comment = postState.comment;
    }
  }
);
```

I tried debug the code step by step. In BlocBuilder, after the if condition fulfilled, postState.comment inputted to comment variable. Then debug's step run to the others line code. But, after some steps, debug run back to BlocBuilder. Because the last called state is CommentState, so it triggers the if condition again.

I thought BlocBuilder only trigger CommentState once and run next line code until the end. But it is not, it is back again and make BlocBuilder trigger CommentState twice. What happened?

Comment: Your builder should be pure from side effects. That is, you should not care much if it's being triggered multiple times. If you want to execute some side effect when the state updates, use `listener` in [`BlocListener`](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=bloclistener). Or if you need both `builder` and `listener`, use [`BlocConsumer`](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocconsumer).

Comment: @DhafinRayhan : i don't understand with "side effect" that you said. But my problem just how to prevent BlocBuilder from called twice. It makes impact, so another code have 2 values because that.

Comment: Yeah, from what you've described you're trying to do side effects in your builder. Don't. _"so another code have 2 values because that"_ that's what side effect is. You don't have to prevent the builder to fire multiple times, because it should be pure anyway. See [this article](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/side-effects-flutter/) to know more about side effects. It also looks like your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @DhafinRayhan : so do you mean i prefer use listener to execute side effect than builder? because builder will always fire multiple times and  we can't prevent that?

Comment: Yes, you **must** use listener to execute side effect. And yes, builder is expected to fire multiple times, just like the build method of a widget. The bloc documentation literally mentioned that [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocbuilder). _"The builder function will potentially be called many times and should be a pure function that returns a widget in response to the state."_

Comment: @DhafinRayhan : but listener cannot rebuild widget, so how to overcome it? i use builder because it can do that, rebuild widget

Comment: Use [`BlocConsumer`](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocconsumer), as I mentioned in my first comment. It has both listener and builder. Put side effect in the listener. Return widget in the builder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256976/discussion-between-ryandra-and-dhafin-rayhan).